# Retirar da página mvc "© 2017 - Nome Projeto"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma page razor que eu chamo dentro de outra página, e por ter esta identificação: © 2017 - CronoParque, aparece duas vezes na "mesma página", já que eu chamo uma, dentro da outra, gostaria de saber, se tem como desabilitar esta opção, da página que eu chamo.
A imagem de como está ficando, para que possam entender melhor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código do minha `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - CronoParque</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-page="/Index" class="navbar-brand">CronoParque</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2017 - CronoParque</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-mask-plugin/src/jquery.mask.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-mask-plugin/src/jquery.mask.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

No meu HTML que eu chamo a página, não tem nenhuma referência da página.

Código da View:

```html
@page @model CronoParque.Pages.HorarioItem.CreateModel

<h4>Horários Itens</h4>
<hr />
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="button" value="Incluir Itens" onclick="abreModal();" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" />
</div>
<form method="post" id="createform">


  @if (Model.Message != null) {
  <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button> @Model.Message
  </div>
  }
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="HorariosVM.Horarios.Id" />
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <table class="table table-responsive" id="tabela">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HorariosItens[0].HoraInicio)
          </th>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HorariosItens[0].HoraFim)
          </th>
          <th>
            Dias
          </th>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HorariosItens[0].Tipolimite)
          </th>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HorariosItens[0].Limiteacessos)
          </th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.HorariosItens) { // Converter Hora Início string horaStg; decimal valor = int.Parse(item.HoraInicio); valor = (valor / 60) % 24; var inicio = valor.ToString().Split(char.Parse(",")); string hora = inicio[0]; try { string minuto
        = "0," + inicio[1]; string m = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(minuto.ToString()) * 60).ToString(); horaStg = DateTime.Parse(hora + ":" + m.Substring(0, 2)).ToString("HH:mm"); } catch { horaStg = DateTime.Parse(hora + ":" + "00").ToString("HH:mm"); }
        //// Converter Hora Fim string horaStg1; decimal valor1 = int.Parse(item.HoraFim); valor1 = (valor1 / 60) % 24; var inicio1 = valor1.ToString().Split(char.Parse(",")); string hora1 = inicio1[0]; try { string minuto1 = "0," + inicio1[1]; string
        m1 = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(minuto1.ToString()) * 60).ToString(); horaStg1 = DateTime.Parse(hora1 + ":" + m1.Substring(0, 2)).ToString("HH:mm"); } catch { horaStg1 = DateTime.Parse(hora1 + ":" + "00").ToString("HH:mm"); }
        <tr>
          <td>
            @(horaStg)
          </td>
          <td>
            @(horaStg1)
          </td>
          <td>
            @if (item.Seg == true) { @("Seg"); } @if (item.Ter == true) { @("Ter"); } @if (item.Qua == true) { @("Qua"); } @if (item.Qui == true) { @("Qui"); } @if (item.Sex == true) { @("Sex"); } @if (item.Sab == true) { @("Sab"); } @if (item.Dom == true) { @("Dom");
            } @if (item.Fer == true) { @("Fer"); }
          </td>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tipolimite)
          </td>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Limiteacessos)
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="EditarItem(@item.Id);abreModal();" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Alterar</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="ExluirItem1(@item.Id);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Excluir</a> @*
            <a asp-page="./Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Editar</a>
            <button asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Excluir</button>*@
          </td>
        </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <label class="control-label">Hora Inicio</label>
                      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="txtHoraInicio" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <label class="control-label">Hora Fim</label>
                      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="txtHoraFim" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <label class="control-label">Tipo Limite</label>
                      <input id="txtTipoLimite" class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <label class="control-label">Limite de Acesso</label>
                      <input id="txtLimiteAcessos" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbSeg" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Segunda</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbTer" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Terça</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbQua" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Quarta</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbQui" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Quinta</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbSex" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Sexta</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbSab" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Sabado</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbDom" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Domingo</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbFer" />
                      </div>
                      <label class="control-label">Feriado</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <a href="#" onclick="closeModal();" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Gravar Item</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="fecha();" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Fechar</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

@*<input type="hidden" id="idHorario" name="idHorario" value="@TempData[" idHorario "]" />
<input type="hidden" id="idItem" value="@ViewBag.ItemId" />*@
<input type="hidden" id="idHorario" name="idHorario" />
<input type="hidden" id="idItem" /> @section Scripts { @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
<script src="~/Scripts/Horarios.js"></script>
<script>
  function abreModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

  function closeModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    SalvarItens1();
  }

  function fecha() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  }
</script>
}
```

Comment: Posta o seu html.

Comment: Toda página criada, aparece com isso, só quero desativar esta função de uma página.

Comment: Pressiona `Control+Shif+F` e procura por 2017.

Comment: Na página que eu preciso eu n consigo localizar, creio que deve ser alguma configuração própria do projeto, preciso desativar, apenas de uma página, para não ficar dois em uma mesma página, já que eu chamo uma página dentro da outra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente em um projeto ASP.NET MVC, o template padrão gerado pelo Visual Studio vem com algumas configurações prontas já. Isso que está vendo é uma delas. Existe um arquivo "compartilhado" que é a View do Layout do seu website. Essa View é carregada em todas as páginas, pois, conforme você falou, você chama uma dentro da outra.

Neste caso, creio que se olhar dentro da pasta `Views`, depois em `Shared`, vai encontrar um arquivo chamado `_Layout.cshtml`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentre dele irá encontrar o que está procurando. Porém, na View da sua página, também deve ter a mesma informação, o que está causando duplicidade. Recomendo remover da página e não do arquivo `_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: Não encontrei na minha View a mesma informação, a única coisa que tem de diferente, é @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}}

Comment: Então vamos fazer o seguinte, coloque o código da sua View da página da foto acima e o código da View _Layout.cshtml. Edite sua pergunta e coloque lá, por favor.

Comment: Editei com a página _Layout.cshtml, a outra página que eu chamo HTML, não tem nenhuma informação da _Layout.cshtml

Comment: E o código da sua View?

Comment: Se eu fizer isso, eu tiro de todos as páginas, preciso tirar apenas de uma, eu tentei fazer dessa forma: @{
    Layout = "";    
    } Porém ele perde os js declarados também. Me retornando erro.

Comment: Sim, acabei falando besteira e editei meu comentário hehe. Tem como colocar o código da sua View? A que possui a tabela da imagem que colocou?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78719/discussion-between-perozzo-and-marianac-costa).

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código da VIew.

Comment: @marianac_costa obrigado por escolher como resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Mariana, muito provável que isto vem na página _Layout.cshtml da pasta Shared.
o Asp.Net possui ela como um padrão inicial como exemplo de página compartilhada com as outras. Para que ela pare de aparecer **apenas** para esta página, você deve retirar o código do html de Layout Compartilhado:

```
ViewBag.Title = "Página";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

De uma olhada e veja se isso resolve pra você.

Comment: Não encontrei na minha View a mesma informação, a única coisa que tem de diferente, é @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}}

Comment: Faça o seguinte, de um **Ctrl+shift+F** e pesquise por 2017, veja se ele traz mais de uma linha na pesquisa